# Can't establish a connection between PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a database for a chat application to store users, friends and messages. I have a MySQL database stored into an online server. I also have two PHP files. One index file and another file which contains a class that it is used in the index file.

mysql.class.php

```
    <?php


class MySQL
{   
    private $dbLink;
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUsername;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $dbName;
    public  $queryCount;

    function MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName)
    {
        $this->dbHost = $dbHost;
        $this->dbUsername = $dbUsername;
        $this->dbPassword = $dbPassword;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;    
        $this->queryCount = 0;      
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }
    //connect to database
    private function connect() {    
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);     
        if (!$this->dbLink) {           
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }else if ($this->dbLink){
            echo 'Success!';
        }
        else if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("set names latin5",$this->dbLink);
            return true;
        }
        unset ($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);     
    }   
    /*****************************
     * Method to close connection *
     *****************************/
    function close()
    {
        @mysql_close($this->dbLink);
    }
    /*******************************************
     * Checks for MySQL Errors
     * If error exists show it and return false
     * else return true  
     *******************************************/
    function ShowError()
    {
        $error = mysql_error();
        //echo $error;      
    }   
    /****************************
     * Method to run SQL queries
     ****************************/
    function  query($sql)
    {   
        if (!$this->dbLink) 
            $this->connect();

        if (! $result = mysql_query($sql,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();         
            return false;
        }
        $this->queryCount++;    
        return $result;
    }
    /************************
    * Method to fetch values*
    *************************/
    function fetchObject($result)
    {
        if (!$Object=mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $Object;
        }
    }
    /*************************
    * Method to number of rows
    **************************/
    function numRows($result)
    {
        if (false === ($num = mysql_num_rows($result))) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return -1;
        }
        return $num;        
    }
    /*******************************
     * Method to safely escape strings
     *********************************/
    function escapeString($string)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            return $string;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $string = mysql_escape_string($string);
            return $string;
        }
    }

    function free($result)
    {
        if (mysql_free_result($result)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }

    function lastInsertId()
    {
        return mysql_insert_id($this->dbLink);
    }

    function getUniqueField($sql)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($this->query($sql));

        return $row[0];
    }
    function testconnection() { 
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);     
        if (!$this->dbLink) {           
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("set names latin5",$this->dbLink);
            return true;
        }
        unset ($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);     
    }       
}
```

index.php

```
<?php


require_once("mysql.class.php");



$dbHost = "host";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "db name";

$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

// if operation is failed by unknown reason
define("FAILED", 0);

define("SUCCESSFUL", 1);
// when  signing up, if username is already taken, return this error
define("SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED", 2);  
// when add new friend request, if friend is not found, return this error 
define("ADD_NEW_USERNAME_NOT_FOUND", 2);

// TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS: if last authentication time of user is older 
// than NOW - TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS, then user is considered offline
define("TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS", 60);

define("USER_APPROVED", 1);
define("USER_UNAPPROVED", 0);


$username = (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && count($_REQUEST['username']) > 0) 
                            ? $_REQUEST['username'] 
                            : NULL;
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? md5($_REQUEST['password']) : NULL;
$port = isset($_REQUEST['port']) ? $_REQUEST['port'] : NULL;

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : NULL;
if ($action == "testWebAPI")
{
    if ($db->testconnection()){
    echo SUCCESSFUL;
    exit;
    }else{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
    }
}

if ($username == NULL || $password == NULL)  
{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
}

$out = NULL;

error_log($action."\r\n", 3, "error.log");
switch($action) 
{

    case "authenticateUser":


        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {                   

            // providerId and requestId is Id of  a friend pair,
            // providerId is the Id of making first friend request
            // requestId is the Id of the friend approved the friend request made by providerId

            // fetching friends, 
            // left join expression is a bit different, 
            //      it is required to fetch the friend, not the users itself

            $sql = "select u.Id, u.username, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
                                        f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
                            from friends f
                            left join users u on 
                                        u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
                            where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
                                         f.requestId = ".$userId." ";

            //$sqlmessage = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";

            $sqlmessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext, u.username from messages m \n"
    . "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";


            if ($result = $db->query($sql))         
            {
                    $out .= "<data>"; 
                    $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
                    while ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                    {
                        $status = "offline";
                        if (((int)$row->status) == USER_UNAPPROVED)
                        {
                            $status = "unApproved";
                        }
                        else if (((int)$row->authenticateTimeDifference) < TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS)
                        {
                            $status = "online";

                        }
                        $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'  status='".$status."' IP='".$row->IP."' userKey = '".$row->Id."'  port='".$row->port."'/>";

                                                // to increase security, we need to change userKey periodically and pay more attention
                                                // receiving message and sending message 

                    }
                        if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))           
                            {
                            while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                                {
                                $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' />";
                                $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                                $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                                }
                            }
                    $out .= "</data>";
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
                // exit application if not authenticated user
                $out = FAILED;
        }



    break;

    case "signUpUser":
        if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
        {
             $email = $_REQUEST['email'];       

             $sql = "select Id from  users 
                            where username = '".$username."' limit 1";



             if ($result = $db->query($sql))
             {
                    if ($db->numRows($result) == 0) 
                    {
                            $sql = "insert into users(username, password, email)
                                values ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ";                          

                                error_log("$sql", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql))   
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $out = SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED;
                    }
             }                      
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "sendMessage":
    if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {   
        if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
        {
             $tousername = $_REQUEST['to']; 
             $message = $_REQUEST['message'];   

             $sqlto = "select Id from  users where username = '".$tousername."' limit 1";



                    if ($resultto = $db->query($sqlto))         
                    {
                        while ($rowto = $db->fetchObject($resultto))
                        {
                            $uto = $rowto->Id;
                        }
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`fromuid`, `touid`, `sentdt`, `messagetext`) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$uto."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."');";                       

                                error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                       
                        $resultto = NULL;
                    }   

        $sqlto = NULL;
        }
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "addNewFriend":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
            {               
                 $friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];

                 $sql = "select Id from users 
                                 where username='".$friendUserName."' 
                                 limit 1";
                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                        {
                             $requestId = $row->Id;

                             if ($row->Id != $userId)
                             {
                                     $sql = "insert into friends(providerId, requestId, status)
                                         values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".USER_UNAPPROVED.")";

                                     if ($db->query($sql))
                                     {
                                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                            $out = FAILED;
                                     }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $out = FAILED;  // user add itself as a friend
                            }                                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }                               
                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }
            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "responseOfFriendReqs":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {
            $sqlApprove = NULL;
            $sqlDiscard = NULL;
            if (isset($_REQUEST['approvedFriends']))
            {
                  $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['approvedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }

                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                    }               

                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlApprove = "update friends set status = ".USER_APPROVED."
                                    where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                ";      
                  }

            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['discardedFriends']))
            {
                    $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['discardedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }

                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                    }                   
                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlDiscard = "delete from friends 
                                        where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                    providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                            ";
                  }                     
            }
            if (  ($sqlApprove != NULL ? $db->query($sqlApprove) : true) &&
                        ($sqlDiscard != NULL ? $db->query($sqlDiscard) : true) 
               )
            {
                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }
    break;

    default:
        $out = FAILED;      
        break;  
}

echo $out;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)
{

    $sql22 = "select * from users 
                    where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' 
                    limit 1";

    $out = NULL;
    if ($result22 = $db->query($sql22))
    {
        if ($row22 = $db->fetchObject($result22))
        {
                $out = $row22->Id;

                $sql22 = "update users set authenticationTime = NOW(), 
                                                                 IP = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' ,
                                                                 port = 15145 
                                where Id = ".$row22->Id."
                                limit 1";

                $db->query($sql22);             


        }       
    }

    return $out;
}

?>
```

The first four variables in index.php must be changed depending on my MySQL server configuration. But still I can't establish a connection between the PHP and the database. Is there something wrong with one of the PHP files?

Comment: Uncomment your `echo` command in `ShowError` and see if it shows an error.

Comment: You've given us WAY too much information. Work on creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to look through pages of code to try to find the problem. Do the work ahead of time of getting rid of everything that's not necessary to show the problem.

Comment: Is your MySQL is on localhost or installed on another host???
What error message are you getting??

Comment: @MiyaG When I load the index.php, it is supposed to show a 1, meaning that the connection was successful. But it keeps showing me a 0, meaning that the connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `MySQL` have the same name as your class. If you're using > PHP4, this is a deprecated way of doing it, you'll need to use the `__construct()` -method.

So, if you're using PHP version newer than PHP4, try with following:

```
<?php

class MySQL
{   
    private $dbLink;
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUsername;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $dbName;
    public  $queryCount;

    function __construct($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName)
    {
        $this->dbHost = $dbHost;
        $this->dbUsername = $dbUsername;
        $this->dbPassword = $dbPassword;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;    
        $this->queryCount = 0;      
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }
}
```